# Android Application Crashes when exported

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk

My android application is the customized version of the Cool reader. When I run the application from eclipse, or debug it on my phone, it runs fine.  But when I sign it, export it, install it, and run it from my phone, it crashes.

In the logcat, I see the following before the application crashes:

```
07-17 21:40:40.371: D/Zygote(1218): Process 3136 terminated by signal (11)
07-17 21:40:40.371: E/InputDispatcher(1331): channel '40b7d8a8 com.myCustomApp/org.coolreader.CoolReader (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
07-17 21:40:40.371: E/InputDispatcher(1331): channel '40b7d8a8 com.myCustomApp/org.coolreader.CoolReader (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-17 21:40:40.451: D/dalvikvm(1331): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 758K, 35% free 9419K/14279K, external 2060K/2410K, paused 85ms
07-17 21:40:40.451: I/WindowManager(1331): WIN DEATH: Window{40b7d8a8 com.myCustomApp/org.coolreader.CoolReader paused=false}
07-17 21:40:40.451: I/ActivityManager(1331): Process com.myCustomApp (pid 3136) has died.
07-17 21:40:40.471: E/ActivityManager(1331): fail to set top app changed!
```

**Update:**
If you are not aware about CoolReader (the open source project I'm using), it jni code, has proGuard configuration, and uses ndk.  It also has normal Java code.  I'm don't have a lot of experience with jni/ndk, or any low level c\c++ code, so I'm not sure what I can do there.

But again, the starngest thing is that it works fine when it runs from eclipse, but the exported version closes on its own.

Comment: The application produces lots of log messages.  If you want all the messages, I can provide them.  Many Thanks!

Comment: A few questions: Anything in the log messages about missing permissions? Are you using any JNI code? If it works on your phone in debug mode but not after exporting, I'd also suspect a ProGuard configuration problem. Do you have ProGuard enabled? If so, as a test, try turning it off and exporting.

Comment: I have updated the question answer your question. There are no permissions related messages, if there were, I don't think it would run from eclipse. I'll look into turning off ProGuard configuration (not sure what it is, so will do some research)

Comment: Removing ProGuard solved the problem.  Do I really need ProGuard? I'm not too concerned about obfuscation, as the project is open source, but I think I need optimization for performance. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You don't need ProGuard, but using it will shrink the .apk file size (perhaps significantly, depending on what you're doing). It may also have some performance benefits (provided it doesn't crash the app, of course. :)) I suspect that ProGuard is removing some Java classes, methods, or fields that are referenced only from native code (which ProGuard wouldn't see). If you knew which ones they were (there may be clues in the stack trace), it would be easy to change the ProGuard configuration to preserve them.

Comment: You could ask about ProGuard configuration on the [CoolReader forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crengine/forums/forum/673936). Maybe someone's addressed this issue already.

Comment: Well, the size wasn't significantly increased after I remove proGuard.  Only about < 1 MB went up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since removing ProGuard clears up the crash, there are two options:

1. Disable ProGuard
2. Tell ProGuard to keep the classes/methods/variables that it is (mistakenly) eliminating.

One thing to try is to add the following rule to your ProGuard configuration:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

This will tell ProGuard to preserve anything that has native code. If the problem is that ProGuard is removing native methods that happen to not be called from Java, this should fix the problem.

Another problem may be that ProGuard is removing Java call-back methods that are called only from native code. You can keep all these by first naming them all using a standard naming pattern (e.g., `<something>Callback`) and then adding this rule:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    *** *Callback(...);
}
```

If the problem is class variables being removed, you'll have to enumerate those explicitly:

```
-keep class com.example.MyClass {
    *** aFieldName;
}
```

You may be able to find other clues about what ProGuard may be wrongly removing by examining the usage.txt file that ProGuard generates when it is run.

Comment: I'll give it a try once3 I get home, and let you know :)